# What are some limitations of the Asterisk Manager Interface (AMI)?

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami, freepbx

It is my understanding that the Asterisk Manager Interface is single threaded.

Can someone please explain to me if this is true, and if so, explain what some of the limitations of this would be?

If calls to the AMI overload the single thread do requests get queued up? Can this cause issues on a system (phones losing registration, poor call quality, etc.)?

Comment: The question you have asked, as is, is quite ambiguous.  AMI is used for several reasons, including receiving system events, performing actions on calls, placing outbound calls, querying system states, etc.  You will get a better answer if you clarify how you expect to use AMI.  Also keep in mind that AMI supports multiple simultaneous connections, so it is hard to call AMI 'single threaded'

Answer (score 0):

You can open 10 AMI sessions in 10 threads and create your own pool.

However very likly if you need more then one, you do something wrong. AMI response usually very fast.